# How to make Youtube short code transfer

Tags: migration, embed, youtube

I have moved my wordpress from wp hosted to privately hosted. I exported my posts and imported them in to my new site. Many posts included youtube embeds that look like this

```
[youtube=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nk50eES-0w]
```

However, the embeds fail to work. I there a plug in that exists that uses this format or will I have to go find a plug in and modify the codes on all the posts ?

Comment: Install [Jetpack](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/) plugin and activate shortcodes from Jetpack settings. These will start working again

Comment: Great :) glad I could help